# Elixir macro rewriting module methods and global __using__ macro

Tags: macros, elixir

With elixir's `__using__` macro and with the aid of `__on_definition__` I can keep track of all methods in a module. What I would like to do is replace all methods in a module with some other implementation. Now it's fairly trivial to create the new methods I want but I also want to remove the existing methods.

Additionally to this, is there a way to apply a macro to several modules without explicitly adding the `use XXX` to each module. In otherwords if I have a folder structure:

- foo/

  - bar/

    - module1.ex
    - module2.ex

Could I dynamically apply the `using` macro to everything in `./foo/bar/`.

To simplify my problem, imagine that for all methods in all modules in the `foo/bar/` folder I want to change there implementation so that they will first run `IO.inspect "called before method"`, aka some kind of before method aop.

Answer (score 2):

`def` is just a macro from `Kernel`. So you could exclude it with `import Kernel, except: [def: 2]` and then create you `def`. Here is something that almost works, except for the return value.

```
defmodule Def do
  import Kernel, except: [def: 2]
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      import Kernel, except: [def: 2]
    end
  end

  defmacro def(call, expr) do
    # caller = __CALLER__
    # IO.inspect call
    # IO.inspect expr

    # import Kernel
    quote do
      Kernel.def unquote(call) do
        IO.puts "do something first"
        unquote(expr)
      end
    end
  end
end

defmodule Special do
  use Def
  import Def

  def test(one, two) do
    IO.puts "one: #{inspect one}, two: #{inspect two}"
  end
end
```

Running in iex

```
Interactive Elixir (1.4.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> Special.test 1, 2
do something first
one: 1, two: 2
[do: :ok]
iex(2)>
```

I left some print statement at the top of the custom `def` macro. You can use this to examine the AST of the inputs to the new `def` macro.

You can find more information in the [Kernel](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex) source code.

I have not thought of an idea to automatically apply the `use` to multiple modules at once. I'm come back and update this if I think of anything.

Comment: Hey Steve, thanks for the reply and I know that I can redefine def. What I was really asking is whether it was possible to not have to explicitly add the usings. 

Maybe its easier if I just say given a directory can I hook into the compiler to change ALL modules in the directory without explicitly calling using or any macros in the module code itself.